# CKEDITOR Error code: cloudservices-no-token-url Angular 2

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I am using `ng2-ckeditor` in my `Angular 5` project. I downloaded offline package and added it. Everything is working fine expect but it is showing error i console `[CKEDITOR] Error code: cloudservices-no-token-url.` I tried to solve it by adding it in `config` file as extra plugin. It is also available in `build-config` but still unable to solve it.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Check this answer which helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/50333575/3452348

Answer (score 9):

You should remove the plugins.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
:
:
:
   config.removePlugins = 'easyimage, cloudservices';

};
```

Answer (score 0):

CloudServices needs an upload url and token url specified either in the ckeditor config file or in your javascript to remove this error message.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    extraPlugins: 'easyimage',
    cloudServices_tokenUrl: 'https://example.com/cs-token-endpoint',
    cloudServices_uploadUrl: 'https://your-organization-id.cke-cs.com/easyimage/upload/'
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check :

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    extraPlugins: 'easyimage',
    cloudServices_tokenUrl: 'https://example.com/cs-token-endpoint',
    cloudServices_uploadUrl: 'https://your-organization-id.cke-cs.com/easyimage/upload/'
} );
```

Defaults to ''

https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-cloudServices_tokenUrl

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved easily, make sure you downloaded the package without the "Easy Image" which requires a paid service "Cloudfare", install the new package and then clear your cache on your browser. Reconfigure your settings for your new download and those errors will go away.