# How to disable ckeditor cloudservices

Tags: javascript, drupal-7, ckeditor

I'm working on a Drupal site that just updated its ckeditor library from 4.5.x to 4.9.2. On one of our servers the image button suddenly stopped appearing and I find the error "Error code: cloudservices-no-token-url." in the browser javascript console when I load any page with ckeditor.

I'm hoping I can disable cloudservices to resolve the error. I tried using config.removePlugins = 'easyimage'; in config.js. Are there other addons that use cloudservices I need to disable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to get rid of EasyImage is not downloading it in the first place.

Please go to [CKEditor download page](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/) and download the package you are interested in but without EasyImage (don't check EasyImage checkbox).

Alternatively use can use [online builder](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder). Please go to builder page, select one of predefined presets and plugins you like but don't include EasyImage plugin. If you are using CKEditor with CKFinder or some other custom file manager or uploader, you need to include [File Browser](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/filebrowser) plugin (available in Full and Standard presets by default).

Comment: I initially had some caching problems that made it look like the full package without EasyImage still had the problems, but with further testing found you are spot on. I replaced the library with one without EasyImage and it works as desired. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the plugin.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
:
:
:
   config.removePlugins = 'cloudservices';

};
```